# Sending java parameters to SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: java, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have java code which has cascading parameters like State and County. If i select State respective county would be displayed in County dropdown. Both will have all option as well. Is there a way to handle it in java? Please let me know

Comment: Yes.  But for a more detailed answer, you're going to need to provide more details of your implementation.  How, for example, are you calling and displaying the report?

Comment: I have something like this Continent, Country, State as three drop downs. If continent selected is Asia then dropdown should display Countries with ALL option, if any country is displayed then it should display state with ALL option. I dont know how to add these cascading dependencies in Java code with query.

Comment: I typically use SQL to accomplish this. Let me know if that could work for you, provide your data schema, and I can help you with the code.

Comment: I want to send the following parameters date, employee dept, location, name and format type PDF/XLS. My java application provides flexibility to create dropdowns with these values the problem is how to map it from my application and send to SSRS report server.

Comment: I figured out by using webservices of SSRS. ReportExecutionServiceSoapStub and created a method which passed ReportExecutionServiceSoapStub and throws SOAPException. Used  axis, axis-wsdl4j to get webservice xml and convert to java. Iterated thru parameters in application's DB and sent it via java to SSRS.